# How to send custom form data to FineUploader Azure Success endpoint?

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using FineUploader 5.13.0 with the Azure Blob Storage end point.

I have it successfully uploading files directly to blob storage, and also successfully hitting my web server success endpoint when the upload is concluded.

However, I am looking for a way to include custom data in the post to the success endpoint.

This bit in the documentation seems to imply that it is possible. 
Under the section "Optional server-side tasks" for "uploadSuccess.endpoint", it says it will send
"Any parameters/form fields you have associated with the file".

However, I just cannot seem to figure out how to do that.

This issue seems to refer to it, but doesn't give enough info.
https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1313

Note, I am not referring to the feature to hook into existing HTML forms as explained on this documentation page:
"Integrating with Existing HTML Forms"
https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/forms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for FineUploader's Request [params](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.params). This allows you to add extra form data.

Eg:

```
new qq.FineUploader({

    // elided

    request: {
        params: {
            testing: "THIS IS A TEST"
        }
    }
});
```

This will show up in the multi-part body of the request:

[image]